# Add discard button when editing

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Manually clear saved question drafts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68957/manually-clear-saved-question-drafts)

When editing a post there is no clear way to discard changes, one can click the `Return to Question/Answer` link but that's not entirely intuitive and it prompts for confirmation to "navigate away from page".

I would suggest adding a <kbd>Discard Edits</kbd> button which I don't think should prompt for confirmation (since it's an explicit action).

The ideal would be to discard edits without prompting but add a Gmail style link to go back to editing from where you left off.

Comment: Usually I'm not in favor of CRs like this, but it would really add a lot of polish to the editing UX. +1

Answer (score 2):

As a two step workaround for this, if the post has an edit history, you can select a previous revision and then the current revision again, which will effectively discard all your edits, without leaving the post and returning again. This will cause the prompt, confirming you want to leave even though you've made changes, but doesn't require reloading the whole page.

Also, ctrl-z, or the "undo" button (top right above the edit text box), will allow you to go through all the changes you have made and undo them, click this enough and you will return to the original state.

Answer (score 2):

For comments:  <kbd>F5</kbd>

For questions:  <kbd>Bakcspace</kbd>

There you have it! SO is so cool that it even has buttons on *your* keyboeard!

Comment: Your backspace smeagol!

Comment: Keybeard with your mousetache?

Comment: I can haz ur kebeard!?

Comment: Funny, I don't have a `Bakcspace` key on my keyboard!

Comment: Sure you do! It just next to the `Any` key!