# How do I "cancel" posting a question?

Tags: support, questions, posting, cancel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Manually clear saved question drafts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68957/manually-clear-saved-question-drafts)

I looked at the related questions and they didn't seem to fit, so sorry if this is a duplicate question.

I am getting really good at the "Rubber Duck" scenario, where I spend all sorts of time trying to figure out the problem, begin writing my question, and then solve my question with some unrelated thought process.

In all of my unasked questions so far, my problem and solution were **not** related to the question as I posed it, so I truly believed leaving the question up and answering it myself would not have benefited the community.  Thus, I've gotten used to my questions being saved as drafts - and this has occurred again today.

Since there is no "cancel post" option, I figured I'd try to clear out my draft by manually clearing all the relevant fields.  But the draft feature is stronger (smarter?) than I, and the draft is left behind.

Therefore, how do I truly "cancel" the question or delete my draft?  Does it eventually clear itself out, or is there a specific action I can perform to do this?  I'm pretty certain it eventually cleared, but I don't know what action I performed to do this.  Was it simply closing the browser?  I can't/don't want to do that at the moment to test :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The draft will be cleared in a week, or if you overwite it with a new question.

Comment: Perfect!  That's what I needed to know.  Thanks!  Too bad I'm asking more questions in meta than SO...

Comment: @D.N. If more people spent time on meta (if only to read the FAQ style posts), I suspect SO would be a better place. :-)