# How can I cancel an answer I started

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to permanently clear an answer draft?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94682/is-it-possible-to-permanently-clear-an-answer-draft)

I decided not to submit an 'answer", but I could not see a cancel button.

What should I do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nothing. Just go to a different page and dismiss the pop-up warning about leaving the page. The system will keep the draft of your answer in case you change your mind. If you don't, just leave it alone.