# How do I get rid of the "saved question input"?

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, draft

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Manually clear saved question drafts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68957/manually-clear-saved-question-drafts)

If I start to ask a question, and then never post it because I have found the answer myself, or realized that it was a "stupid question", then the site remembers what I typed for ever, and I always have to delete it before trying to ask another question. Is there a way to clear the question input text?

Comment: Is the old text even preserved when you actually ask another question? If so, then I guess that's a bug.

Comment: No, it is not preserved, but atm I seem to be trying to ask many questions, and then not posting them, so it I notice it more clearly. Also, it does seem to be a duplicate, as you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the text with a single space and wait for the draft to save.  (You'll see the *draft saved* message appear when this has happened.)

Comment: While that's true, it does seem a bit...intrusive to have to clear the input and then hang around 'til the timer removes/'resaves' the entered text...

Comment: Or, @David, isn't a bit odd to want to clear the saved question to start with? It's only visible when starting to write (a new) question.

Comment: __Please, please fix this.  I hate getting caught in the question trap, with the site always thinking I'm trying to answer the question.__

Answer (score 2):

This is really bad UI design.

I'm always getting caught in the trap, where I start answer, realize that I don't want to finish, but then everytime I go to that page (until I answer another question) it brings up the text.  There have been times when I've automatically posted an answer that I then had to delete, because I'm moving fast and didn't think of my ghost answer being there.

What's so hard about a `cancel` button for the draft (like we have for the Edit)?

Comment: Just in case: if the `cancel` button would always be visible, and then would also clear the text, then to me that is like an evil `<imput type="reset">` button. Then: no, please. (But surely the team can figure out something smarter.)

Comment: @Arjan, I want it to actually clear the draft cache, so that I don't keep getting the page with the pre-filled (maybe blankly) box.  I want it to completely forget that I tried to answer that question.  I'm not really hung up on the implementation details.

Comment: +1 We definitely agree on this! Even if it hurts absolutely nothing, I hate seeming remnants of an abandoned answer there. I compulsively obsess about things like this.