# How to remove a question in the Ask Question editor

Tags: support, asking-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Manually clear saved question drafts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68957/manually-clear-saved-question-drafts)

Anyone else have this issue or am I missing something?  I made a question, rather in depth, to ask about why I was getting an error.  I had the stack trade, my debug stuff, a lot of code, the whole 9 yards.  I didn't really want to be putting that much stuff out there so I was hesitant to post and was actively working on resolving this issue.  Upon solving the issue I had a huge question in stackoverflow ready to go.  But, I didn't want to post it.  Unfortunately, there was no way to remove it, as every time I would return to the "Ask Question" area, it would re-populate the entire entry with my question again.

Any ideas how to remove a question that is in the editor?  My only idea was to post a different question...

Comment: Select All -> Delete?

Comment: "Questi0n"? Really now?

Comment: It wouldn't let me use "Question" in the text but it is relevant.

Comment: I do know what you're talking about - I see the same thing in the Answer editor.  Select All -> Delete does not work.  It seems as if there needs to be a "Cancel" button or such.

Comment: Select all -> delete -> add one space works for me. This is meant to be a feature (although I can see how it can be annoying sometimes)

Comment: Duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/68957/145673

Comment: Just put a space, wait until the autosave kicks in, then it's "removed".

Answer (score 2):

I've answered this before... my typical answer is "ignore it".

What you're seeing is the draft of your question. If you no longer need that question, just wait until you come up with **another** question, and just replace the text that's currently saved as a draft with the new question.

It's not harming anything to leave it there.

If you **really** want it to go away just replace it with something else. Or, use George Edison's [Save Drafts On Demand](https://stackapps.com/questions/2086/manual-draft-save-save-a-draft-on-demand) userscript.

Comment: *ahem* skype. wtf?